# Tabbing through a Lightning:tabset using tab button on keyboard?

Tags: community, lightning, lightning-events

I have a set of 6-8 tabs which show up through the lightning tabset component, and I would like to be able to go through each of these tabs using the specific 'Tab' key, instead of left and right.

```
          <lightning:tabset class="{!v.styleClass}" selectedTabId="{!v.selectedTabId}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.navigationListItems}" var="navigationListItem">
                    <lightning:tab tabindex="0" onactive="{!c.tabSelected}" id="{!navigationListItem.Id}" title="{!navigationListItem.Name}">
                        <aura:set attribute="label">
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!navigationListItem.Badge ? navigationListItem.Badge.length > 0 ? v.showBadges ? true : false : false : false}">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!navigationListItem.Badge}" var="badge">
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </aura:if>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.styleClass != 'labelOnlyTab'}" >
                                <lightning:icon iconName="{!navigationListItem.ImageUrl}" size="x-small" />
                            </aura:if>
                            <span tabindex="0">{!v.styleClass != 'iconOnlyTab' ? navigationListItem.Name : ''}</span>
                        </aura:set>
                    </lightning:tab>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:tabset>
```

This is a snippet of the relevant code, with this setup I can move through the tabs with left and right, but for accessibility purposes I need to do this with the tab key. With the tabindex set I can tab to the element, but it does not get made active or in focus, even if I push enter.

I have tried various things like putting a button inside the tab, or putting an event listener for the Enter button, but having trouble with that as well.